# How to pass an object with form in Symfony2

Tags: forms, object, select, symfony, doctrine

I have a problem. At the beginning, this is my action which create form:

```
public function wyswietlDostepneTerminyAction($kategoria) {
    $zlecenie = new Zlecenia();

    $form = $this->createForm(new ZleceniaAddType(), $zlecenie);

    return array ('form' => $form->createView(), 'kategoria'=>$kategoria);
}
```

'Zlecenie' object has 'Kategoria' field of 'Kategorie' type (its from relation).

Method which persist entity:

```
public function noweZlecenieAction(Request $request) {
    $entity  = new Zlecenia();
    $form = $this->createForm(new ZleceniaAddType(), $entity);
    $form->bind($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('pokaz-zlecenie', array('id' => $entity->getId())));
    }

    return array(
        'entity' => $entity,
        'form'   => $form->createView(),
    );
}
```

And form class:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('opis')
        ->add('klient', new KlientType())
        //->add('kategoria')
    ;
}
```

Normally, I can add field like:

```
->add('kategoria','entity', array('class'=>'Acme\MyBundle\Entity\Zlecenia')
```

and select Kategoria from list.

But the problem is: I don't want to choose Kategoria from select list or checkbox list. I want to use predefined $kategoria object. Of course (if must exist) 'Kategoria' field must be hidden. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a data transformer that will transform the data entered by the user in a form into something else.
In your case you will transform a Kategoria ID submited by the user into Kategoria object. The best option for you here is define that your "Kategoria" property in your form will be of hidden form type. 
When the form is rendered you will have a input hidden that will store the ID of your Kategoria object. When the form is submited the transformer will reverse that ID to the correspondent Kategoria Object. As you want to define a default Kategoria, in your controller after you create the Klient object you should set the Kategoria.

If you follow this source http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html , everything will went fine. Any questions just say

Answer (score 1):

Try this, tweaking to your directory structure:  Formtype:

```
    public function buildForm( FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options ) {
        if ( isset( $options['attr']['kategoria'] ) ) {
            $kategoria = $options['attr']['kategoria'];
        }
        else {$kategoria=null;}
        $builder
        ->add( 'opis' )
        ->add( 'klient', new KlientType() );
        if ( $kategoria ) {
            $transformer = new KategoriaTransformer( $em );
            $builder->add(
                $builder->create( 'kategoria'
                    ->add( 'kategoria', 'hidden', array()
                    )
                )
                ->addModelTransformer( $transformer );
            }  else {
                ->add( 'kategoria', 'entity'
                     , array( 'class'=>'Acme\MyBundle\Entity\Zlecenia' )
                }
                ;
            }
```

And the transformer:

```
    namespace Acme\MyBundle\Entity\Zlecenia\Transformer;

    use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
    use Symfony\Component\Form\DataTransformerInterface;
    use Symfony\Component\Form\Exception\TransformationFailedException;

    class kategoriaTransformer implements DataTransformerInterface
    {
        /**
        * @var ObjectManager
        */
        private $em;

        /**
        * @param ObjectManager $em
        */
        public function __construct(ObjectManager $em)
        {
            $this->em = $em;
        }

        /**
        * Transforms an object (kategoria) to a string (id).
        *
        * @param  Issue|null $kategoria
        * @return string
        */
        public function transform($kategoria)
        {
            if (null === $kategoria) {return "";}
            if (is_object($kategoria) && 
                method_exists($kategoria, "toArray")){
                $kategoria=$kategoria->map(function ($ob){
                     return $ob->getId();});
                return implode(",",$kategoria->toArray());
            }
            return $kategoria->getId();
        }

        /**
        * Transforms a string (id) to an object (kategoria).
        *
        * @param  string $id
        * @return Issue|null
        * @throws TransformationFailedException 
        *         if object (kategoria) is not found.
        */
        public function reverseTransform($id)
        {
            if (!$id) {
                if($this->multi) {return array();}
                return null;
            }

            if (strpos($id,',') !== false) {
                $id=explode(',',$id);
            }
            $qb=$this->em->getRepository(
            'Acme\MyBundle\Entity\Zlecenia\Repository\kategoria'
            )
            ->createQueryBuilder('k');
            $qb->andWhere($qb->expr()->in('i.id', $id));
            if (is_array($id) || $this->multi){
                $kategoria=$qb->getQuery()
                ->getResult();
            } else {
                $kategoria=$qb->getQuery()
                ->getSingleResult();
            }
            if (null === $kategoria) {
                throw new TransformationFailedException(sprintf(
                    'A kategoria with id "%s" does not exist!',
                    $id
                    ));
            }

            return $kategoria;
        }
    }
```